# How to center fontawesome icon inside position:absolute div?

Tags: html, css, sass, font-awesome

I need to center font-awesome icon inside div with position:absolute. I need to make triangle in the left bottom corner like on image:

[image]

My HTML:

```
<div class="image-wrapper">
   <img src="image-source">
   <div class="bottom-triangle">
       <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

My Sass:

```
.image-wrapper {
  position: relative;

  img {
    min-width: 100%;
  }

  .bottom-triangle {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 50px 0 0 50px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent $primary_color;
    bottom: 0;

    .fa-plus {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
  }
}
```

With this code I have triangle like on image, but my font-awesome icon located outside of the blue triangle.

Comment: Both classes are absolute. Make the .bottom-triangle relative while the .fa-plus still absolute.

Comment: @JoshuaDelaCruz That should make no difference as absolute positioned elements are positioned relative to the nearest _positioned_ ancestor (i.e. the first that is not static)

Comment: Well, I thought that would make a difference somehow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your `.bottom-triangle` has no width and height, so the browser has no idea it could place the icon inside of the triangle. Giving the class a width and height should do the trick. Since this would mess with the border, I'd probably go with a pseudo element, for example

```
.bottom-triangle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  bottom: 0;

  &:after {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 50px 0 0 50px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent blue;
}
```

You can then place your icon in the `.bottom-triangle` like you used to.
I've built an abstracted example in [this JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/3m0257h2/3/)